# PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Name of User

Tags: stored-procedures, psql

I was wondering if there was a way to detect the log in name of the user executing the query which triggers a stored procedure?  Say, I have a trigger on `table_a` that fires when a particular column is changed.  I would like to retrieve the name of the logged in user who executed the query which triggered the stored procedure running.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a recognized keyword called `current_user` that does the exact thing I want - holds the username of the current user executing the query.